# dataDisk.image parameter in Azure Resource Template

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

Is there any Azure Resource Template documentation? I am trying to recreate a VM using Resource Template and the only thing I am missing is creating a data disk from image the same way the OS disk is created. I edited the JSON template:

```
          "dataDisks": [
        {
          "lun": 0,
          "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachines_testVM_name'),'-disk-1')]",
          "createOption": "FromImage",
          "vhd": {
            "uri": "[concat('https', '://', parameters('storageAccounts_rmtemplatetest6221copy_name'), '.blob.core.windows.net', concat('/vhds/', parameters('virtualMachines_testVM_name'),'-disk-1-201649102835.vhd'))]"
          },
          "caching": "ReadWrite"
        }
      ]
```

But I get following error in Azure when deploying the template

> Required parameter 'dataDisk.image' is missing

So far the only way I got to recreate the data disk was to delete above code from the JSON template and then use Powershell after the machine is created without the data disk, but I would like to automate deployment with resource template only.

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen this and there is nothing regarding 'dataDisk.image'

Comment: Are you looking to copy an existing data disk? or create an empty one?

Comment: I already copied the data disk and I want to attach it to newly created VM. So both data disk and OS disk are already precreated. I think I will just use one of the quick start templates as suggested by astaykov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you have the template configured to make a copy of an image, and you have no image specified.

You need to either set the createOption to fromImage, and specify an image

```
"dataDisks": [
 {
  "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'-dataDisk')]",
  "lun": 0,
  "createOption": "FromImage",            
  "image": {
    "uri": "[variables('dataDiskUrl')]"
    },
  "vhd": {
    "uri": "[variables('dataDiskVhdName')]"
    }
}
],
```

or, if you just want to use an existing disk, you can use attach, (you can also use empty in this configuration, and it will create an empty disk)

```
"dataDisks": [
{
    "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'-dataDisk')]",
    "lun": 0,
    "createOption": "attach",          
    "vhd": {
    "uri": "[variables('dataDiskVhdName')]"
   }
}
],
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing and looking for, in my case there is no need to create another copy of an image, just attach the already existing image.

Answer (score 1):

In the Azure quick start templates you can find JSON template for creating VM using custom images, including Data disks:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-user-image-data-disks

Just one very important note - the targed storage account should be **same** account where your VHDs reside.

There is no standing documentation on the JSON Schema. The best source is to check out the Schema itself, so:

- https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json
- http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.Compute.json#/resourceDefinitions/virtualMachine

**UPDATE**

When you create VM based on custom image, including data disks, you **must** create the entire VM in the same storage account where your custom data disks reside. There is no option, as of today (2016-05-10) to instruct ARM to copy VHDs across storage accounts.

This all was, if you want to create a VM from custom image with Data Disks.
If you just want to create the VM with new, empty data disks, then you can use the following quick start template:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-multiple-data-disk

where you only define the desired size of the data disks and where they should be stored.

Comment: I don't understand what  "the targed storage account should be same account where your VHDs reside" means, are you saying that you can't create a vm and spread the disks across multiple storage accounts? I'm also not sure that this answers the question, it just points to the (closest thing there is) to documentation

Comment: I was creating the VM in the same resource group as storage account containing both OS and data disks, so I think that all requirements were met. Error was indicating that I was missing some parameter so I don't think it was related to location of storage accounts. Also the 101-vm-multiple-data-disk quick start template is not working for me: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/1938